# appium with no reset does not close the simulator after execution

Tags: selenium-webdriver, appium, simulator, appium-ios

I have to run some test suite on two remote machines.

So, after one suite, i reset the app and for the next suite, app starts well.

But the problem is, after completing the total execution

```
driver.quit()
```

just close the app but it does not close the simulator as

```
no reset is true.
```

So, is there a way to close the xcode simulator using appium or selenium?
I do not want to use ssh and full reset option.

I also do not want to use

```
killall "Simulator" as it needs ssh connection.
```

Comment: what is the use case ur acheiving by quiting the simulator?

Comment: At the end of execution, simulator will be closed from pc.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 String closesim[] = {"killall","iOS Simulator"};
        Runtime.getRuntime().exec(closesim);
```

Comment: it does not close the simulator on another machine.

Comment: its just about placing the above code on the end of both executions

Answer (score 0):

You can try directly close simulator by passing below code in you AfterClass,Or AfterSuit method . which close all the simulator which is open in system.

For my case its working i am not sure in your cases its work because if you pass below command in terminal you can find its close your simulator.

> runtime.exec("xcrun simctl shutdown all");